# How to link LevelHelper to cocos2d-x project

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

We are doing 1 game for Android and IOS using cocos2d-x. For that we followed [http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started](http://this.) link.
Everything is working fine except when we try to link/include LevelHelper to our project, its throwing below error

```
undefined reference to `LevelHelperLoader::LevelHelperLoader(char const*)'
```

Below is Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloworld/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Box2D \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/LevelHelper \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/LevelHelper/

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static box2d_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) $(call import-module,cocos2dx) $(call import-module,Box2D)
```

We don't know where we are going wrong. Any clue is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer for this. I needed to add all the `.cpp` files of `LevelHelper` to `Android.mk` like below

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloworld/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/LevelHelperLoader.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Utilities/LHDictionary.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Utilities/LHObject.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Utilities/LHArray.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/SHDocumentLoader.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHSprite.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHTouchMgr.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHSettings.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHPathNode.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHParallaxNode.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHNode.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHLayer.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHJoint.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHFixture.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHCuttingEngineMgr.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHCustomSpriteMgr.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHContactNode.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHContactListener.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHContactInfo.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHBezier.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHBatch.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/Nodes/LHAnimationNode.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/CustomClasses/LHUntitledClass.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LevelHelper/CustomClasses/TemporaryDummyClass.cpp
```

for further assistance, please refer [this](http://www.levelhelper.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1641&p=10837&hilit=android&sid=3727f9ccd166beb1f82c7089c4396aa9) link. Hope it helps other users too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the LevelHelper is only compatible with cocos2d-x for iOS, Mac only, no one tested on the android platform yet. And on the  cocos2d-x website, it does not said any progress about android. Here is the link http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/14

Comment: hmmm yeah, nobody tested this on Android it seems... I did not find any related posts also... Anyway, I want to wait n see for some more time